# MotionLayout OnSwipe spring physics stop working after transitionToStart/End()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-motionlayout

I have the following MotionLayout:

[image]

The Transition XML is as follows (I omitted the keyframes because they don't matter for this example).

```xml
<Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/collapsed"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/expanded"
    motion:duration="500"
    motion:motionInterpolator="cubic(0.2,0,0,1)">
    <OnSwipe
        motion:springDamping="63.973"
        motion:autoCompleteMode="spring"
        motion:onTouchUp="autoComplete"
        motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
        motion:touchAnchorId="@id/now_playing_touchable_area"
        motion:touchAnchorSide="top"
        motion:springStopThreshold="1.0E-4"
        motion:springMass="2.6"
        motion:springStiffness="389.76" />
    <KeyFrameSet>
        ...
    </KeyFrameSet>
</Transition>
```

When I start my app for the first time, and I begin a swipe, you can see that the layout tracks my finger correctly. It moves at the same speed as my finger, until I release, after which it uses spring physics to autocomplete to a start/end state.

However, I have also bound a click listener to `transitionToStart()` and `transitionToEnd()` (depending on whether we're currently expanded/collapsed), and as soon as I trigger those once, the OnSwipe spring physics and tracking stop working. The layout no longer tracks my finger, but now uses the cubic motionInterpolator defined for the Transition.

How do I combat this? I would like to be able to use `transitionToStart/End()` programmatically, while still keeping spring physics for regular swipes.

EDIT: I have some more useful information. It turns out, after the first `transitionToStart/End()`, the OnSwipe still uses spring physics, except it seems they are being *modified* by the cubic motionInterpolator. How do I know this? If I set my motionInterpolator to linear, I experience no issues. Before and after a `transitionToStart()/End()`, the OnSwipe behavior works as intended and tracks my finger like it's supposed to.

So a more specific question now is, how can I get the OnSwipe behavior to ignore the motionInterpolator and just always use linear (and why is it being affected by it in the first place)?

Comment: I am a little unclear as to what you are saying.
You are driving a transition in two ways: 
1. An onSwipe with a spring effect. 2. calls to transitionTostart/end using a cubic interpolator.
Are you saying the onSwipe stops working after you use the transition?

It should not happen. It might be the case that you are triggering the transitionToStart/End somehow.
 You can check that by making the duration very fast motion:duration="100"  or putting print statements where you trigger.

Comment: @hoford I can confirm that the transitionToStart/End are **not** being triggered when I start a swipe (I have print statements whenever I trigger).

Comment: @hoford I have added more information to my question which might help you figure out what the problem is. It is all very weird behavior to me.

Comment: Thanks, It is a bug sort of.  The interpolator does not get injected till you run the transition. Logically the interpolator should always be installed. (Which is not what you want). I will describe a workaround in an answer after I test the workaround.

Comment: That makes sense. I have found a solution to achieve what I want, so I will post the answer here later today when I have the chance. Hopefully other people who have the same problem no longer need to pull their hair out like I did :-) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of messing around with it, I have found the solution.

To restate what my goal is:

- I want to be able use the OnSwipe feature of my MotionLayout's transition, such that it perfectly tracks my finger and uses spring physics when I release to snap to a starting/ending state.
- I also want to be able to trigger `transitionToStart/End` programmatically (which in my case happens to be hooked up to a setOnClickListener on the collapsed bar, see the GIF in the original question).

For OnSwipe to track my finger correctly, it needs the motionInterpolator to be **linear**, but I don't want to make the programmatic triggers to be linear as well, because it doesn't look very natural. I want them to be *cubic* instead, so this means I will need to **switch between two transitions depending on whether it was triggered programmatically or by OnSwipe**.

So let's create two Transitions for this:

```xml
<MotionScene
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/programmatic_transition"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/collapsed"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/expanded"
        motion:duration="500"
        motion:motionInterpolator="cubic(0.2,0,0,1)">
        <KeyFrameSet>
            ...
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/onswipe_transition"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/collapsed"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/expanded"
        motion:duration="500"
        motion:motionInterpolator="linear">
        <OnSwipe
            motion:springDamping="60"
            motion:autoCompleteMode="spring"
            motion:onTouchUp="autoComplete"
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@id/now_playing_anchor"
            motion:touchAnchorSide="top"
            motion:springStopThreshold="0"
            motion:springMass="2.6"
            motion:springStiffness="389.76" />
        <KeyFrameSet>
            ...
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>
...
</MotionScene>
```

Notice that both of them are identical transitions, both transitioning from the "collapsed" state to the "expanded" state, both with the same KeyFrameSet. The only differences are that one of them has a cubic motionInterpolator (I called this one "programmatic_transition"), and the other has a linear motionInterpolator paired with an OnSwipe tag with my desired spring physics (called "onswipe_transition").

Now that we have our two transitions, we need to programmatically switch between them, depending on whether we're currently swiping, or just using `transitionToStart/End()`.

The latter is easy: just set the transition right before calling `transitionToStart/End()`.

```kotlin
fun collapse() {
    motionLayout.setTransition(R.id.programmatic_transition)
    motionLayout.transitionToStart()
}
fun expand() {
    motionLayout.setTransition(R.id.programmatic_transition)
    motionLayout.transitionToEnd()
}
```

For the swipes, we'll use a transition listener to detect when a swipe is started, so that we can set the "onswipe_transition" instead.

```kotlin
motionLayout.setTransitionListener(object : TransitionListener {
    override fun onTransitionTrigger(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean, p3: Float) {}
    override fun onTransitionStarted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
        if (dragging) {
            motionLayout.setTransition(R.id.onswipe_transition)
        }
    }
    override fun onTransitionChange(p0: MotionLayout, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Float) {}
    override fun onTransitionCompleted(p0: MotionLayout, p1: Int) {}
})
```

Notice how we *only* set the transition when our finger is dragging across the screen (this magical variable `dragging`). The last step now is to make sure `dragging` is `true` when our finger is dragging across the screen, and `false` when our finger has released the screen.

For that, we'll override `onInterceptTouchEvent` on our MotionLayout so we can keep track of this.

```kotlin
override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    val isInTarget = // check if the position of the event is within the view that we want to allow to be dragged from

    return if (isInTarget || dragging) {
        when (ev.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                dragging = true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                dragging = false
            }
        }
        super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
    } else {
        true
    }
}
```

This `isInTarget` value will depend on your own design.

So there we have it. I have gone nearly crazy by figuring all of this out over the past two days, but I'm pleased to say that this solution has fixed the problem flawlessly. Hopefully I'll have helped someone else out there trying to something similar!

Comment: This is a great solution. 
My similar concept tried to avoid additional non xml code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug but even when it is fixed it would not do what you want.

The basic problem is you want two transition between the two states.
There is a work around that is not elegant.

1. create to alias states collapsed2 and expanded2
2. create transitions collapsed->expanded2 and expanded->collapsed2
3. create auto transitions expanded2->expanded2 and collapsed->collapsed2

This some what easy to do in the MotionEditor but it is messy

```
    <ConstraintSet
        android:id="@+id/collapsed2"
        motion:deriveConstraintsFrom="@+id/collapsed" />
    <ConstraintSet
        android:id="@+id/expanded2"
        motion:deriveConstraintsFrom="@+id/expanded" />

    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/click_to_expand"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/expanded2"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/collapsed"
        motion:motionInterpolator="cubic(0.2,0,0,1)"
         />

    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/click_to_collapse"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/collapsed2"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/expanded2"
        motion:motionInterpolator="cubic(0.2,0,0,1)"
        />

    <Transition
        motion:autoTransition="jumpToEnd"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/expanded"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/expanded2" />
    <Transition
        motion:autoTransition="jumpToEnd"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/collapsed"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/collapsed" />
```

To transition

```
        if (progress < 0.5) {
            mMotionLayout.setTransition(R.id.click_to_expand);
            mMotionLayout.transitionToState(R.id.expanded2);
        }
        else {
            mMotionLayout.setTransition(R.id.click_to_collapse);
            mMotionLayout.transitionToState(R.id.collapsed2);
        }
```

The power of this approach is you can customize the transitions with there own
keyframes

- interpolator
- arcMode (motion:pathMotionArc="startVertical")
- keyFrames
- stagger

Longer term I will be fixing the bug and adding a few features to make the use case simpler.

Comment: I like this a lot! At the end of the day, both our solutions try to trick Android into thinking there are more states/transitions than there actually are. I think in my case, it ended up being simpler to duplicate the transitions since they were not that large, as opposed to my state XML which is more elaborate. But it's very good to know that it can be done both ways! Thanks :-)