# Use AndroidX motion layout to implement a player bottom bar (like Youtube)

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx, android-motionlayout

I'm having a lot of troubles figuring out how to use the `MotionLayout` to animate a Youtube-like bottom player bar.

After trying to understand how this layout works for a few hours using [the official examples](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/main/ConstraintLayoutExamples/motionlayout) and a lot of googling, I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73254556/motionlayout-onswipe-spring-physics-stop-working-after-transitiontostart-end) which feature a GIF chowing *exactly* what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Unfortunately, the complete code is not there so I can't understand how the author did it.

All I have for now is this:

[image]

Two problems here: the animation instantly jumps from 0 to 100 and the view doesn't collapse, it keeps occupying the whole screen.

I don't know if it's related but that part of the UI is contained in a fragment. Here is the activity layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/surface"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/appbar_wrapper"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <!-- 
        This is the fragment that contains the view that lies 
        beneath the player controls. It's not visible on the image above
    -->
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
      android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
      android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:defaultNavHost="true"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav"
      tools:layout="@layout/fragment_artists" />

    <!-- 
        This is the fragment that contains the fragemtn that contains 
        the controls that won't collapse
    -->
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
      android:id="@+id/now_playing"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="audio.funkwhale.ffa.fragments.NowPlayingFragment" />
  </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my fragment's UI:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    android:id="@+id/now_playing_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/elevatedSurface"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:motionDebug="SHOW_ALL"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/fragment_now_playing_scene">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:id="@+id/header"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <SquareImageView
      android:id="@+id/now_playing_details_cover"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      android:padding="8dp"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/cover"
      tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    
  <!-- The rest of the UI is stripped to keep the code short -->
  </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
</layout>
```

and my scene:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <Transition
    app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
    app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    app:duration="1000"
    app:motionInterpolator="linear" >

    <OnSwipe
      app:dragDirection="dragUp"
      app:touchAnchorId="@+id/header"
      app:touchAnchorSide="top" />

    <KeyFrameSet>
      <KeyAttribute
        android:alpha="0"
        app:framePosition="75"
        app:motionTarget="@id/now_playing_details_controls" />
    </KeyFrameSet>

  <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint android:id="@+id/header" />

    <Constraint
      android:id="@id/now_playing_details_cover"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
  </ConstraintSet>

  <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint android:id="@id/header" />

    <Constraint
      android:id="@id/now_playing_details_cover"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/header"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/header"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/header" />
  </ConstraintSet>
  </Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

---

## Edit

Thanks to [hoford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2558442/hoford), I could resolve some of the problems. However, while animation works correctly, the layout itself doesn't move. This is how it should look like:

[image]

This implementation uses a simple `FrameLayout` in combination with `BottomSheetBehavior` instead of `MotionLayout`. The bottom sheet itself is fragment that uses databinding.

The current implementation using a `MotionLayout` looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the parts of the UI in the fragment now animate correctly, but the `FragmentContainerView` itself doesn't collapse. I tried several combination of `layout_height` on the `FragmentContainerView` and the `MotionLayout` within but I can't replicate the behaviour of the `BottomSheetBehavior` implementation.

I feel like `MotionLayout` doesn't play well inside a `FragmentContainerView` and I couldn't find a case using fragments in Android's examples.

Here is the layout for the activity

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- The component displaying the albums list -->
  <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/surface"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
      android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
      android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:defaultNavHost="true"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav"
      tools:layout="@layout/fragment_artists" />
  </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

  <!-- The fragment of the player controls bar that should collapse -->
  <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/now_playing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/appbar_wrapper"
    android:name="audio.funkwhale.ffa.fragments.NowPlayingFragment" />

  <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
      android:id="@+id/appbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBar"
      app:backgroundTint="@color/elevatedSurface"
      app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
      app:navigationIcon="@drawable/funkwhaleshape"
      tools:menu="@menu/toolbar" />
  </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the updated layout of the player controls bar that should collape:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <data>
  <!-- snip -->
  </data>

  <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    android:id="@+id/now_playing_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/elevatedSurface"
    app:motionDebug="SHOW_ALL"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/fragment_now_playing_scene">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:id="@+id/header"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <audio.funkwhale.ffa.views.SquareImageView
      android:id="@+id/now_playing_details_cover"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_margin="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/cover"
      tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/now_playing_details_info"
      android:layout_width="32dp"
      android:layout_height="32dp"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/now_playing_details_cover"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/now_playing_details_cover"
      style="@style/IconButton"
      android:layout_gravity="top|end"
      android:background="@drawable/circle"
      android:contentDescription="@string/alt_track_info"
      android:src="@drawable/more"
      app:tint="@color/controlForeground" />

  <!-- Snip -->    
  </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
</layout>
```

And the updated scene:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <Transition
    app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
    app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    app:duration="1000"
    app:motionInterpolator="linear" >

    <OnSwipe
      app:dragDirection="dragUp"
      app:touchAnchorId="@+id/header"
      app:touchAnchorSide="bottom" />

    <KeyFrameSet>
      <KeyAttribute
        android:alpha="0"
        app:framePosition="10"
        app:motionTarget="@id/now_playing_details_info"
      />
      <KeyAttribute
        android:alpha="0"
        app:framePosition="10"
        app:motionTarget="@id/now_playing_details_controls"
      />
    </KeyFrameSet>

  <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint
      android:id="@+id/header"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

    <Constraint
      android:id="@id/now_playing_details_cover"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Constraint
      android:id="@+id/now_playing_details_info"
      android:layout_width="32dp"
      android:layout_height="32dp"
      android:layout_margin="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/now_playing_details_cover"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/now_playing_details_cover"
    />

    <Constraint
      android:id="@+id/now_playing_details_controls"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:alpha="1"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/now_playing_details_cover"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    />
  </ConstraintSet>

  <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint
      android:id="@id/header"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    />

    <Constraint
      android:id="@id/now_playing_details_cover"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/header"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/header"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/header"
    />

    <Constraint
      android:id="@+id/now_playing_details_info"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_margin="0dp"
      android:alpha="0"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/now_playing_details_cover"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/now_playing_details_cover"
    />

    <Constraint
      android:id="@+id/now_playing_details_controls"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:alpha="0"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    />
  </ConstraintSet>
  </Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

Comment: A general mistake people make when seeking help is showing the broken animation.
Without showing exactly what is missing/wrong. "It still does not show xxx as you can see below"  How do we know what / where is XXX that is NOT being seen?

Ideally you show correct start and end pictures and then the broken animation. 
Alternatively state the id of the view that should be seen.  So  we can look at the xml.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I edited again my question.

Comment: Small fix (probably not the problem)  ConstraintSet does not go in a Transition.
now_playing_details_controls is in the MotionScene but not in the layout.
My guess is you have a few things wrong. Start with a simplified standalone project with just Button, TextView, Views in a MotionLayout with the right id's.  Get the MotionScene giving you the correct behavior.

Comment: Some assumptions that I have seen in the past that you might be making.  MotionLayout  can only control its children NOT its children's children or its parent.
 Media players have default use a window which "floats" above your app for performance reasons there is usually and XML attribute to disable it.

(Will add more in a new answer)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect many things are wrong a few things I notice:
 says to track the upward movement of the top of @id/header
But start and have the exact same

Which means the header does move
because `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`  + height="0dp"
implies it top is pinned.

In general before you think about the swipe part.
Focus on getting the two constraintSets to have the start and end state you want.
Which typically involves modifying constraints in the ConstraintSet
If it is laying out the way you want

Then the onSwipe anchor needs to be with the moving object

see https://youtu.be/XtnAZXM26wQ for a brief overview on onSwipe

### The problem

You say "`FragmentContainerView` itself doesn't collapse"
But the`FragmentContainerView` is not a child of the MotionLayout.

Layouts can only control direct children. The only other thing a layout can do is change its wrap size. You seem to be trying to control the MotionLayouts Parent.

The way this would typically be done is motionLayout is at the base of everything you want to control.

You might be able to make the MotionLayout and the fragment transparent.
But you would still have touch handling missing.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot. However, I still have one problem. Could you look at the edit?

Comment: So, basically, what you mean is: there's no way I can reuse the XML and Kotlin code for that part using a fragment if I want to use this bottom sheet in multiple places? For instance in both portray and landscape layouts? I *must* duplicate the XML in both layout and I can't use a fragment *at all* because the motion layout won't be able to control what's inside — in case the motion layout ancapsulates the fragment — of its parent — in case the fragment encapsulate the motion layout?
That seem to entirely defeat the purpose of fragments and data binding, doesn't it?

Comment: Not just MotionLayout No View can control its parent. The flow of control is parents control children.  
You can create a custom Fragment which uses motionLayout inside it to do animation. But the custom Fragment is driving.

Comment: Many components have limitations such that they are not a good fit for one particular need